# Toggling Between Sets of Images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, toggle

Okay, so I'm designing a simple website using Skeleton grid system. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="gallery" class="nine columns">
    <div id="thumb1" class="three columns">
        <a id="cglink" href="#">
            <img src="images/cg1.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="thumb2" class="three columns">
        <a id="balink" href="#">
            <img src="images/ba1.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="thumb3" class="three columns">
        <a id="l7link" href="#">
            <img src="images/l71.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
#gallery {
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    margin: 0;
}

#gallery .three.columns {
    padding: 19.3px 0 13.5px 0;
}

#thumb1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#thumb2 {
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#thumb3 {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.three.columns img {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.three.columns img:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}
```

So what I want to do is when I click on one of the images, it will toggle a hidden div. The html for that is here:

```
<div id="cg" class="nine columns">
    <img src="images/cg1.jpg">
</div>
<div id="ba" class="nine columns">
    <img src="images/ba1.jpg">
</div>
<div id="l7" class="nine columns">
    <img src="images/l71.jpg">
</div>
```

So I have basic toggle scripts applied currently.

```
$('#cg, #ba, #l7').hide();
$('#cglink').click(function () {
    $('#cg').toggle('fade', 400);
});
$('#balink').click(function () {
    $('#ba').toggle('fade', 400);
});
$('#l7link').click(function () {
    $('#l7').toggle('fade', 400);
});
```

So what I have currently works. However I discovered this bug where if I toggle, let's say, `#cg` and then try to toggle `#ba`, the `#ba` will appear under. It wasn't so pretty. So what I want to do is this: When I click `#cglink` and then decide to click on `#balink`, the `#cg` div should hide and `#ba` div would show. I'm not sure if I made sense, so if I did not, just comment and I will articulate further.

I think people set flags to check if another `div` is already open so that it can hide.  However I'm still a beginner so I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a common indentifyer to your anchors, like so;

```
<div id="gallery" class="nine columns">
    <div id="thumb1" class="three columns">
        <a href="#" id="cglink" class="toggle_btn"><img src="images/cg1.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="thumb2" class="three columns">
        <a href="#" id="balink" class="toggle_btn"><img src="images/ba1.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="thumb3" class="three columns">
        <a href="#" id="l7link" class="toggle_btn"><img src="images/l71.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then to the elements you are toggling:

```
<div id="cg" class="nine columns toggle_img">
    <img src="images/cg1.jpg">
</div>
<div id="ba" class="nine columns toggle_img">
    <img src="images/ba1.jpg">
</div>
<div id="l7" class="nine columns toggle_img">
    <img src="images/l71.jpg">
</div>
```

Then toggle:

```
$('#cg, #ba, #l7').hide();

$('a.toggle_btn').on('click', function () {
    var elem = $('#' + this.id.replace('link',''));

    $('.toggle_img').not(elem).fadeOut(400);
    elem.toggle('fade', 400);
});
```

And remember next time that using classes will let you target multiple elements at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a function to handle the displaying of your elements. All your click events would reference this function like so

```
$('#cglink').click(function() {showElement('#cg'));
$('#balink').click(function() {showElement('#ba')});
$('#l7link').click(function() {showElement('#l7')});
```

Your showElement function can make sure all elements are hidden and only fade in the necessary one.

```
function showElement(whichElement) {
    $("#gallery div").stop().hide() //hide all elements. we call stop() to stop any fading
    $(whichElement).fadeIn();
}
```

This is the basic example. You can also hide all elements at the start bu calling the function with no params. e.g: showElement(). I also recommend you use css3 for the fading by adding and removing a class instead of animating it through JS.

EDIT: I quickly created a JS fiddle with a faster approach. You wont have to manually add events for each button by using the href attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/EbGCx/